# Facebook Marketing API - How to validate an ad image?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Creating an ad Ad Creative for an image works ok using the Facebook Marketing API.

```
curl \
-F 'name=Link Page Post Ad Creative' \
-F 'object_story_spec={"page_id":<PAGE_ID>,"link_data":{"message":"try it out","link":"your_link","image_hash":"<IMAGE_HASH>"}}' \
-F 'access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>' \
'https://graph.facebook.com/<API_VERSION>/act_<AD_ACCOUNT_ID>/adcreatives'
```

The challenge is to validate the image through the Facebook Marketing API (Facebook has for instance a policy about using maximum 20 % text in an ad image). I made an Ad with the Ad Creative containing an Ad Image. This image had too much text and did not meet Facebooks policy about image resolution. The problem is that the Facebook Marketing API did not say anything about that in the HTTP response. It returned status success, even though the image was too small.

However, when I activated the Ad through the GUI (ads manager at business.facebook.com), I noticed that the image was removed in the preview of the ad. Watching the ad preview in Ads manager I noticed an error when entering edit-mode. The error message in the GUI told me that the image resolution was too low. How can I get this error message when I call the API? I need to handle this programmatically.

Comment: What endpoint did you use to upload the image? /adimages? Can you upload the image somewhere so we can reproduce? Do you have the ID of the uploaded image?

Comment: Yes, the endpoint is        "https://graph.facebook.com/<API_VERSION>/act_<AD_ACCOUNT_ID>/adimages". Example of an image too small is:
{"images":{"toosmall.jpg":{"hash":"33b00de56f8259d7e54ad747673aa386","url":"https://fbcdn-creative-a.akamaihd.net/hads-ak-xpf1/t45.1600-4/10736893_6036022230676_2021208235_n.png"}}}

An image with more than 20 % text is:
{"images":{"toomuchtext.jpg":{"hash":"3c93e4ccc5bbf0ea1e0f93500083e334","url":"https://fbcdn-creative-a.akamaihd.net/hads-ak-xat1/t45.1600-4/10737107_6036022363876_1530785737_n.png"}}}

Comment: @Flaxfield Yes, the endpoint is act_<AD_ACCOUNT_ID>/adimages. For image too small and image with too much text, see the comment above which contains the image hashes.

Comment: @Roemer Have you had the chance to test the image validation with the image-hash in the comment above?

Answer (score 1):

You can now use the recommendations API to pre-validate Campaigns, AdSets and Ads.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-recommendation/

To validate the creative, you would send it in POST request along with the Ad data to the /ads endpoint with the params `execution_options=['validate_only', 'include_recommendations']`.

This will return a recommendations object which you can use to display a message to the user. If the image has more than 20% text a message with the code **1885113** will be present.